# нужно перенести все нули в конец

Tags: python

нужно перенести все нули в конец
входные данные:

```
7
1 3 0 -4 0 0 5
```

выходные данные:

```
1 3 -4 0 5 0 0
```

код

```
n=input()
m=([int(x) for x in input().split()])
a=list()
for i in m:
    if i == 0:
        m.remove(i)
        a.append(i)
c=m+a
print(*c)
```

почему переносит не все нули?

Comment: Нельзя менять список по которому вы делаете `for`. (На самом деле можно, но требуется специальное разрешение от министерства списков).

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с `filter()`

```
c = list(filter(lambda x: x, m)) + list(filter(lambda x: x == 0, m))
print(*c) # 1 3 -4 5 0 0 0
```

Вариант с двумя промежуточными списками:

```
c1, c2 = [], []
for i in m:
    if i:
        c1.append(i)  # сюда складываем не нули
    else:
        c2.append(i)  # сюда - нули
print(*(c1 + c2))  # 1 3 -4 5 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8]

arr = [v for v in arr if v != 0] + [0] * arr.count(0)
```

или можно чуть-чуть сократить

```
arr = [v for v in arr if v] + [0] * arr.count(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Плохо менять список внутри цикла `for` по этому списку. Когда вы вызываете `remove`, цикл начинает пропускать элементы. От этого можно избавиться хитро переписав цикл. Но я не буду вас учить плохому.

Вот код который решает задачу сортировкой. Ключ выбран так что нули "тяжёлые", остальные числа (даже не числа а строки) "лёгкие":

```
input()
print(*sorted(input().split(), key=lambda v: v == '0'))
```

> ```
> $ echo -e "7\n1 3 0 -4 0 0 5" | python reorder.py
> 1 3 -4 5 0 0 0
> ```

**P.S.** Это не самый эффективный способ в терминах О-большого (вы ведь знакомы с О-большим?). Зато он компактный и быстрый на практике, его просто написать и не надо отлаживать.

**P.P.S.** Сортировка в Питоне стабильная. То есть, "не нули" сохраняют исходный порядок. Не уверен что это важно, но как есть так есть.

Comment: А зачем сортировать, если можно просто перенести все не нули в новый список, затем дописать в него нужное количество нулей, а потом присвоить его первоначальному?

Comment: @avp, потому что "его просто написать и не надо отлаживать".

Comment: Источник вдохновения: Джон Бентли, Жемчужины программирования.

*В начале 60-х Вик Высоцкий (Vic Vissotski) работал с программистом, которому нужно было транспонировать матрицу 4000 на 4000 элементов, хранившуюся на магнитной ленте. Все записи имели один и тот же формат и были длиной порядка нескольких десятков байт. Первому варианту программы, который был предложен этим программистом, потребовалось бы около 50 часов на выполнение задачи. Как удалось Высоцкому уменьшить это время до
получаса?*

Comment: Интересно, сколько у него лент было. Неужели пересортировал  по столбцам?

Comment: @avp , да, он добавил к записям их номера в транспонированной матрице и запустил универсальную программу для внешней сортировки. Полезный трюк.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант в Вашем стиле и не меняет последовательность введённых значений. (здесь первый input() вообще не нужен, просто для задачи)

```
a=[] 
k=0
input()
for i in input().split():
    if int(i) != 0:
        a.append(int(i))
    else:
        k+=1
a = a + [0]*k
print(*a)

Ввод:
7
1 0 2 0 1 0 3

Вывод:
1 2 1 3 0 0 0
```

Вообще, если делать точно по заданию, то так:

```
import sys

n=int(input("Cou items: "))
m=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
if len(m) < n:
    print("Too few items!")
    exit(0)
if len(m) > n:
   m = m[:n]

a=[]
k=0

for i in m:
    if i != 0:
        a.append(i)
    else:
        k += 1
a=a+[0]*k
print(*a)
```

Ввод/вывод:

```
Cou items: 7
1 2                                                                                                 
Too few items!

Cou items: 5                                                                                        
5 0 4 0 3 0 1                                                                                       
5 4 3 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Простое превращение вашего кода в рабочий:

```
for i in m.copy():
          ^^^^^^^
```

Теперь итерируемся по копии списка, поэтому итерация не ломается при изменениях списка.

Comment: Или `for i in m[:]:`

Comment: @MarianD Да, но я за "дзен Питона": "явное лучше неявного", `copy` - это явное копирование.

Comment: Я тоже за Дзен Питона: «Простое лучше, чем сложное.» ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`перенести все нули в конец` может означать, что работать нужно с одним списком,т.н. работа на месте, "inplace"

Это нетрудно сделать за линейное время:

```
m=([int(x) for x in "1 3 0 -4 0 0 5".split()])
n =len(m)
k = 0
for i in range(n):
    if m[i]:
        m[k] = m[i]
        k += 1

m[k:] = [0]*(n-k)
print(*m)
```